# Is it possible to develop a wordpress plugin that can upload and display a HTML5 app?

Tags: wordpress, html

I have a desktop app that generates small HTML apps (a zipped folder with a single HTML page, a bunch of scripts with WebGL stuff and a bunch of media files).

Now I would like to make this HTML app easy to deploy to wordpress through a plugin that would:

1. Let the user upload the zip file from his hard drive
2. Unzip the contents and store them somewhere
3. Create a page that displays the HTML app

I'm not looking for actual code yet, just to know that this is possible and that it doesn't violate some constraint. Of course, pointers to information on how to achieve this are welcome.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question is quite vague....

Comment: @n00dl3 Vague?? ... :) ... it's a project description, and we don't provide help with that here at SO, it is way to broad

Comment: @LGSon I know it's broad but I just can not find any information about what is essentially hosting a small web app within WP. I'll take the question down if it is deemed useless.

Comment: If you google `develop a wordpress plugin` and `deploy a html5 app with wordpress` you'll find many links

Comment: @LGSon I don't know a lot about wordpress but the links i see seem to be how to use wordpress as an app which I think is different from embedding an app into regular wordpress pages

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give pointers since it's a really broad question, but as for your plugin requirements: all is possible via php and thus, all is possible in a WP plugin.